# how to get an unknown number of integers into array in c

Tags: c

I need to write a program in c that gets integers as input from the user.

input example:

> 10 20 50 70

The user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then the input is over.
I can't think of a condition to make it happen. I tried to write:

```
int grades[1000];
int i=0;

while(scanf("%d", &grades[i])!=EOF)
{
     i++;
}
```

It is not working.

Comment: perhaps read the documentation of `scanf()` instead of making assumptions about its return value. Also, do **NOT** use `scanf()`. Use `fgets()` along with `strtol()`.

Comment: No. This won't work. `scanf()` is going to block and wait for more numbers to come. Use `fgets()` instead to read the whole line, and then `sscanf()` to extract each number.

Comment: Explain " not working."

Comment: What should happen if "10 20 xyz 70" is entered?

Comment: we have some restricting rules so we can't use most of the c functions. I found a solution int here, someone wrote a scanf using bitwise operations. did'nt fully understand that but it's short and works

Answer (score 2):

Reading a *line* of user input and then parsing is really the best approach as with [@The Paramagnetic Croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804759/2410359)

If code can not pre-define an input buffer size or *must* parse the line while it comes in then using `scanf("%d",...` is OK.  Non-elegant code occurs with finding the `'\n'`.

```
#define N 1000
int grades[N];
int i=0;

for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  // Consume leading white-space, but not \n
  int ch;
  while ((ch == fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && isspace(ch));

  // normal exit
  if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) break;

  ungetc(ch, stdin);
  if (1 != scanf("%d", &grades[i])) {
    // Non-numeric data
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I tried something along these lines but am totally unskilled with `scanf()` due to a life(CPU)long aversion. Marked up.

Comment: @Weather Vane  I feel your pain.  Although code _can_ do this all with `scanf()`, it is ugly.  Even here, code uses `fgetc()/ungetc()` for the finding \nemo part.

Answer (score 1):

If you need read an entire line, then read an entire line, simple as that. If you google "C read line", you will most probably end up reading the documentation of `fgets()`. Then you google "C convert string to integer", and you perceive that there exists a function called `strtol()` in the C standard library. Armed with these two weapons, and applying some logic, you can deduce something like this:

```
const size_t max_numbers = 1000; // however many

int numbers[max_numbers];
size_t index = 0;

char buf[LINE_MAX];
while (index < max_numbers && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    char *p = buf;
    char *end;
    while (index < max_numbers && *p && *p != '\n') {
        numbers[index++] = strtol(p, &end, 10);
        p = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: After `numbers[...`, suggest adding some error tests like `if (p == end) break;` to deal with non-numeric input.

Comment: @chux right. Also, one must reset and check `errno`, so using `strtol()` absolutely correctly is a bit ugly; still better than `scanf()` & co., though.