# How to prevent user from entering more or less input than required in C?

Tags: c, input, fgets, scanf

I want the user to enter just two integers and not more than two or less than two. Also, upon invalid input, I wish to print an error and prompt the user to enter the two integers again. The user should enter two integers delimited by space and not a newline. Thus, for example:
1) Valid input is: 1 2
2) Invalid input: 1
3) Invalid input: 1 2 3

I have tried it with following two approaches:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

   int first;
   int second;
   printf("Enter input:\n");
   int returnValue = scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);
   while(returnValue != 2){
        printf("Invalid input. Please enter again: \n");
        returnValue = scanf("%d %d", &first, &second);
   }
   printf("First: %d Second: %d\n", first, second);
   return 0;
}
```

In this first approach involving scanf, I am unable to prevent the user from entering each integer on newline. Neither am I able to limit the input to just 2 numbers. That is, if the user inputs more than 2 integers, then program is accepting first 2 integers and ignoring third. I want to print error in that case.

My other approach involves fgets and sscanf:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  int first;
  int second;
  printf("Enter input:\n");
  char line[20];
  fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
  int returnValue = sscanf(line, "%d %d", &first, &second);

  while(returnValue != 2){
     printf("Invalid input. Please enter again: \n");
     fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
     returnValue = sscanf(line, "%d %d", &first, &second);
  }

  printf("First: %d Second: %d\n", first, second);
  return 0;
 }
```

In this approach, I am able to print error if the user hits enter after entering just one integer. But I am unable to limit the input to just 2 numbers. That is, if the user inputs more than 2 integers, then program is accepting first 2 integers and ignoring third. I want to print error in that case.

So my question is, are my requirements achievable by modifying first approach as well as second approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Without hardware support (e.g. a keyboard with all letters disabled, some method to electrocute the user if they hit the letter A, etc) it is impossible to PREVENT the user from entering any input they choose.   The most you can do is accept the input, and check it.  If invalid input is encountered, some choices are to ignore the bad parts, ignore some block of data (e.g. a whole line if it contains any bad input), or simply discard input and keep asking until the user enters something valid.

Comment: "So my question is, are my requirements achievable by modifying first approach as well as second approach?" --> Yes, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27805565/2410359) but not worth it.  Go with [@David Bowling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41917246/2410359)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `%n` conversion specification after the two `%d` conversions. The `%n` conversion specification does not match any characters, but stores the number of characters read to this point in the format string. So, in the call:

```
sscanf(line, "%d %d %n", &first, &second, &bufPos);
```

if the second `%d` is reached, then `bufPos` will hold the index of the character after the last character read in `line`. Since there is a space before the `%n`, zero or more white-space characters will be read and skipped over before the index value is stored in `bufPos`. Thus, after a valid entry, `bufPos` will indicate the `\0` terminator. If any other character is found in `line` at this index, there were extraneous characters in the input.

Here is a modified version of your second code example. After `fgets()` reads a line of input, `sscanf()` is used to scan the string. If fewer than 2 matches are made, or if `line[bufPos]` is not `'\0'`, then `badInput` is set to `true`. The input loop is a `do` loop that executes once, and continues to execute so long as `badInput` is `true`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                 // for exit()
#include <stdbool.h>                // for bool type

#define BUF_SIZE  100

int main(void)
{
    int first;
    int second;
    char line[BUF_SIZE];
    int returnValue;
    int bufPos;
    bool badInput = false;

    do {
        if (badInput) {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter again: ");
            badInput = false;
        } else {
            printf("Enter input: ");
        }
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("Error in fgets()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        returnValue = sscanf(line, "%d %d %n", &first, &second, &bufPos);

        if (returnValue < 2 || line[bufPos] != '\0') {
            badInput = true;
        }

    } while (badInput);

    printf("First: %d Second: %d\n", first, second);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
Enter input: 1
Invalid input. Please enter again: 1 2 3
Invalid input. Please enter again: 
Invalid input. Please enter again: 1 2
First: 1 Second: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent issues when asking for `char *` you can use the [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). 
If you are not forced to get two in one `scanf`you could use this function:

```
int secure_input(int max, int min) {
    int choice,buffer;
    do {
        choice = -1;//initialize in a values not included among min and max
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        while ((buffer =  getchar()) != '\n' ? buffer != EOF : false); // empty the buffer to avoid infinite loop
    } while (choice > max ? true : choice < min); 
    return choice;
}
```

In your main function you just to call the function like that:

```
first = secure_input(2;1);
```

Comment: On the rare input error, the value of `choice` may or may not still be `-1`.  Better to test the return value of `scanf()`.  Casting to `char` in `buffer = (char) getchar()` leads to an infinite loop when end-of-file occurs and `char` is unsigned.  Best to use `int buffer` and drop the casting.

Answer (score 0):

Different from other answers, you could also parse the input using [`strtok()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm), then checking how many numbers were found. This approach is complicated, but it does offer a different outlook on the problem.

Inside your `while()` loop, you can check how many spaced numbers were found from `fgets()`, then if only `2` were found, then you can `break` out of the loop. Otherwise, keep searching. Once out of the loop, then you can just `sscanf()` two integers from the most recent input read.  You can also use [`strtol()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) to check if integers are valid.

**Note:** `strtok()` is reeantrant, and it does modify the string that it parses. So in this case, you might need to create a copy of it somewhere. You can use [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) or [`malloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to do this.

Here is some example code that shows this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 20
#define BASE 10

int main(void) {
    char line[LINESIZE];
    const int n = LINESIZE;

    char *number, *copy, *endptr;
    const char *delim = " ";

    int first, second, check, invalidnum;
    size_t slen, count;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter input: ");
        if (fgets(line, n, stdin) == NULL) {
            printf("Error reading buffer from fgets()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        slen = strlen(line);
        if (slen > 0 && line[slen-1] == '\n') {
            line[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Buffer overflow detected\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        copy = strdup(line);

        count = 0;
        invalidnum = 0;
        number = strtok(copy, delim);
        while (number != NULL) {
            check = strtol(number, &endptr, BASE);
            if (endptr == number || check == 0) {
                invalidnum = 1;
                break;
            }
            count++;
            number = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        free(copy);
        copy = NULL;

        if (count != 2 || invalidnum) {
            printf("Invalid input\n\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d", &first, &second) != 2) {
        printf("Unexpected error from sscanf()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("first = %d, second = %d\n", first, second);

    return 0;
}
```

This is just another approach to your problem. In terms of simplicity, @David Bowling has the better idea, and I would suggest using his.